# VBA for Double Click multiple cells one after another

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in cells B2:B3000, whenever I double click a cell it calls other macro to generate an invoice, but in this way I have to double click 3000 times. Is there any code which can double click each and every cell in the given range.

Currently my codes looks like

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Cells <> "" And Target.Column = 2 Then
Cancel = True

Call CreateInvoice(Target.Row)
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just use a standard sub with a loop:

```
Sub lpCells()
    Dim i as Long
    For i = 2 to 3000
        CreateInvoice i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, where I have to put his code in same code before double click ......or insert a new module and then copy and paste this.